# Change button class if value true or false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two buttons with opposite states "Freeze" and "Unfreeze". When the database record is in a false state, I want to show the button "Freeze" below:

```
<%= form.submit "Freeze", class: 'bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border border-blue-700 rounded' %>
```

When the database record is in a true state, I want to show the "Unfreeze" button here:

```
<%= form.submit "Unfreeze", class: 'bg-white-500 hover:bg-white-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border border-blue-700 rounded' %>
```

I was thinking something like this, but I am not sure (also, this does not have the text change...):

```
<tr class=<%= dbrecord.frozen ? "bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border border-blue-700 rounded" : "bg-white-500 hover:bg-white-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border border-blue-700 rounded" %>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make it very simple?

```
<% if dbrecord.frozen? %>
  <%= form.submit "Unfreeze", class: 'bg-white-500 hover:bg-white-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border border-blue-700 rounded' %>
<% else %>
  <%= form.submit "Freeze", class: 'bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border border-blue-700 rounded' %>
<% end %>
```

IMHO this is easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Not my favorite way of doing this, but you can do:

```
<%= form.submit(dbrecord.frozen ? 'Unfreeze' : 'Freeze', class: 'bg-white-500 hover:bg-white-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border border-blue-700 rounded') %>
```

However, please be wary of the toggle pitfall.
Often these types of toggle buttons are implemented with a toggle in code which is error-prone. Make sure you perform the task asked, not just toggling the value.
For example, imagine the value of the DB field is `frozen: true` and the page displays `Unfreeze`. Then the underlying value is changed to `frozen: false` perhaps by the same user in another browser tab. Now the original page will still show the button with `Unfreeze` text. The user then forgets what they've done before, and want to make sure the record is unfrozen, so they click the original `Unfreeze` button on the original page. If it is setup to just toggle the DB value, it will now be incorrectly set to `frozen: true`. Make sure that you perform the task asked, not just performing some toggle. I've seen this done incorrectly so many times.